# jquery Ajax dataType text error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out why this is triggering the alert.  The error value is undefined. add_size.php is just a simple update query and it is returning a string response.  The query works fine and the record is updated.  Why is the success not being triggered?

```
$('#size_add_btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    sizeboxvalue = $('#size_name').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_size.php",
        data: {name: sizeboxvalue},
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(text) {
            $("#sizeRow").prepend("<div class='col-lg-4'><input type='checkbox' name='attr_size[]' value='"+ text +"' > " + text + "</div>");
        },
        error:function(err){
            //handle your error
            alert('did not work ' + err + 'e: ' + e);
        }
    });
});
```

php file:

```
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
$sql = "update attributes set size=concat(size, ',$name');";
$mysqli->query($sql);
$result->close();
echo $name;
```

Comment: Please post your php file, and describe more the error that you retrieve

Comment: Does your javascript console report a 500 error?

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:6send jquery.js:6x.extend.ajax jquery.js:6(anonymous function) product:751x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5v.handle

Answer (score 1):

Its because the response is not text.
So you should add the text header before the echo statement in the add_size.php

So the final code will looks like

```
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
$sql = "update attributes set size=concat(size, ',$name');";
$mysqli->query($sql);
//$result->close();
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $name;
```

Comment: That did not help.  Still get the alert triggered.

Comment: It updates the database record fine.  err is "undefined" and so is e

Comment: can u tell me what is the response in the console.not the alert.

Comment: sorry, I posted the console reply in my previous replies to others.

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:6send jquery.js:6x.extend.ajax jquery.js:6(anonymous function) product:751x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5v.handle

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the line

```
$result->close();
```

in the php file. There was no $result! Why is it always so obvious?!